# Implementation details of Windows Performance Counters

Tags: windows, performance, overflow, reset

I am new to Windows performance counters. I am working on a project that uses custom performance counters. I want to understand how windows performance counters are actually implemented. I am looking for answers to the following questions.

1. What happens to performance counter values when machine restarts?
2. When would one set raw values for performance counters?
3. Do these counters ever overflow?

thanks,
Imran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance counter is not like a counter for numbers and it doesn't grow infinitely and cannot overflow. This is the answer for the third question.

Performance counter is a metric bound to the time. For example, it could be number of bytes sent or received in every moment of time, or hard drive throughput. Or number of active sessions in the database or the operating system itself. You can `win+R -> perfmon`, then click `system monitor` in the tree at left and then click green 'plus' button to get the list of the all counters found in your system.

I don't think that this is possible or at least could be needed to provide the data when the machine is powered off, but after restart, the performance data generation would be restored. This is for the first question.

And the answer to the second question: when you have something which provides some new sort of performace data, you need to provide data for it. Here is the link to the documentation for the process of producing the data: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa373165(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Why can't a performance counter grow infinitely? There is absolutely nothing stopping a performance counter from incrementing its value infinitely. The question now is how it the value stored, which would, most likely, show that it, indeed, can overflow. Secondly a performance counter isn't bound to the time. SOME are but by far not all. Thirdly performance counter values are stored in the RAM and after restart would NOT be restored but restarted. Overall 2/10 answer, very bad.

Comment: @J.Doe feel free to provide a better one